# standard zsh completion for arguments of a zsh function

Tags: shell, zsh, zsh-completion

if I type the following where `record` is a zsh function

`record ls`

how do I write a zsh completion for `record` such that if I write

`record ls -`

it will use zsh's completion for ls e.g.

```
-1              -- single column output
-A              -- list all except . and ..
-B              -- print octal escapes for control characters
-C              -- list entries in columns sorted vertically
```

the record function:

```
function record () {
    local fp="`date +%F_%H-%M_%s`"
    $@ 2>&1 | tee "${fp}.log"
}
```

edit  `time` and `/usr/bin/time` seems to do this e.g

if I do `time ls -<tab>` it will give me `ls`'s completion, how I do this for my own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called `_precommand`, this should do it for your `record` command

```
compdef _precommand record
```

Comment: where should this `compdef ...` be written? on the left of the function definition?